# Push to an array from get:method

Tags: arrays, angularjs, push, factory

EDIT: Solved the question thanks to you. list() instead of list. 
Such a stupid question.

Why pushing to array in a factory like this doesn't work?
It works only if I make a push function inside the factory.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.factory('registeredUsersService', function() {
    var registeredUsers = [];
    return {
        list: function () {
            return registeredUsers;
        }
    }
});


app.controller('registerController', function ($scope, registeredUsersService) {
    registeredUsersService.list.push({username: 'a', password: 'b'});
});
```

Comment: When I push like this I can't see results, but when moving the push method to inside the factory, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try registeredUsersService.list() instead of registeredUsersService.list:

```
app.controller('registerController', function ($scope, registeredUsersService) {
    registeredUsersService.list().push({username: 'a', password: 'b'});
});
```

BTW, i haven't test it.
If not ok, please create a plnkr so i can help you

Comment: Thanks! It works!
I can't believe I made such a stupid mistake!

Comment: I usually make such mistakes too:)

Answer (score 0):

Because list is the function, not the array, try this:

```
registeredUsersService.list().push({username: 'a', password: 'b'});
```

Note the parenthesis list(). Or, you can also expose registeredUsers as a public property of the service, which is the same in this case, i.e.

```
app.factory('registeredUsersService', function() {
    return {
        registeredUsers = []
    }
});
```

Then use it like this:

```
app.controller('registerController', function ($scope, registeredUsersService) {
    registeredUsersService.registeredUsers.push({username: 'a', password: 'b'});
});
```